# Delete all the text from file using an array

Tags: powershell

I have a code snippet as below:

```
$array1=@()
foreach($datec in $datecontent) { 
    $dc = $datec -split '/'
    $mon = $dc[0]
    $day = $dc[1]
    $year = $dc[2]
    if($thisweekdays -contains "$mon/$day/$year"){
        $datec | Add-Content "C:\Previous_Week_Latest.txt"
        $array1 += $datec
    }
    else{
        #Do Nothing
    }
}
```

Previous_Week_Latest file contents:

```
8/18/2015
8/13/2015
```

I have another text file containing dates as shown below. I am doing so many other things and getting created this file.

```
8/18/2015  
8/13/2015  
8/07/2015  
7/31/2015  
7/23/2015
```

I don't want those dates which are in the array, since I need to do some more operations with this text file. Basically **what I need to achieve** is that whatever there in the $array1 finally, I need to delete those from the text file. Something like this:

```
Get-Content "C:\split_weeks_temp.txt" | Where {$_ -match "$array1"} | Set-Content "C:\split_weeks.txt"
```

Can someone please help me at this?

Comment: I am having trouble with your explanation. So are you only trying to keep the dates in a file that match one of the dates in an array? Also why are you splitting the date in your code example just to rejoin it again later? Can we have some sample data and sample desired output perhaps?

Comment: Sure.. Will edit it now..

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that `$array1` contains the properly formatted data just like you show in your example.

```
8/18/2015
8/13/2015
```

And that you just need to filter the contents of the other file where it will omit those dates in `$array1`. I am still investigating but you using `-match`  in this way is the problem. Since it is an array you could just use `-notin` or `-notcontains`.

If you just have PowerShell 2.0

```
Where {$array1 -notcontains $_}
```

Or easier to undersand with PowerShell 3.0

```
Where {$_ -notin $array1}
```

I am still trying to figure out the issue with your current logic. You don't really explain what is wrong with your example.

**Actually...**

Perhaps there is trailing spaces in the date strings? I think that has something to do with it since you have spaces after all the dates you have posted in the question that are part of the "file".